# Laravel 5.4 Webpack Uglify: Output exceeds 32000 characters

Tags: php, laravel, webpack

I have upgraded from laravel 5.3 to 5.4 and switched over to using webpack instead of gulp. Everything works fine when running

```
npm run dev
```

But as soon as I run it for production

```
npm rum production
```

I get the following warnings.

```
 95% emitting

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 25146ms

 WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
 WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
 WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
 WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
 WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
```

I have added this piece of code, (not even sure if this is valid) im not getting any errors on build though to my webpack.mix.js file.

```
mix.options({
    uglify: {
        output: 50000
    }
});
```

These warning i get on my local homestead dev environment and on the production server.

Just the normal laravel dependancies (jquery, bootstrap) gets built to app.js

All my 3rd party vendor script n build to vendors.js

All my custom code I build to custom.js

Just to see if this solves the issue but it does not.

**UPDATE**

When I remove this vendors part the warning goes away, is there a better way to include these scripts?

```
// Vendors
mix.scripts([
    paths.vendors + 'jquery/jquery-ui.min.js',
    // paths.node + 'pjax/pjax.js',
    paths.vendors + 'pjax/jquery.pjax.min.js',
    paths.node + 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js',
    paths.node + 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.buttons.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'form-validation/dist/js/formValidation.js',
    paths.vendors + 'form-validation/dist/js/framework/bootstrap.js',
    paths.vendors + 'detect/detect.js',
    paths.vendors + 'fastclick/fastclick.js',
    paths.vendors + 'jquery/jquery.slimscroll.js',
    paths.vendors + 'jquery/jquery.blockUI.js',
    paths.vendors + 'jquery/jquery.nicescroll.js',
    paths.vendors + 'jquery/jquery.scrollTo.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'modernizr/modernizr.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'pace/pace.min.js',
    paths.node + 'moment/moment.js',
    paths.vendors + 'bootstrap-datepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js',
    paths.vendors + 'notifyjs/dist/notify.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'notifications/notify-metro.js',
    paths.node + 'sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'waitMe/waitMe.min.js',
    paths.node + 'Select2/select2.js',
    paths.node + 'summernote/dist/summernote.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/jszip.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/pdfmake.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/vfs_fonts.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.html5.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.print.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.keyTable.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.responsive.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/responsive.bootstrap.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.scroller.min.js'
], 'public/js/vendors.js' );
```

These ones are causing the size issues

```
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/jszip.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/pdfmake.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/vfs_fonts.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.html5.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/buttons.print.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.keyTable.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.responsive.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/responsive.bootstrap.min.js',
    paths.vendors + 'datatable/dataTables.scroller.min.js'
```